# Celery: Stop an infinite loop running as a background thread

Tags: python, multithreading, signals, celery

I am trying to utilize threading.Thread with Celery to work like a daemon.  On a larger scope, the threads will poll hardware sensors as a part of a web UI-powered thermostat, but narrowed-down, this is the bit I'm stuck on:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import worker_init
from celery.signals import worker_process_shutdown

from threading import Thread
from threading import Event

from time import sleep


class ThisClass(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.shutdown = Event()
    self.thread = Thread(target=self.BackgroundMethod)

  def Start(self):
    self.thread.start()

  def Stop(self):
    self.shutdown.set()

  def BackgroundMethod(self):
    while not self.shutdown.is_set():
      print("Hello, world!")
      sleep(1)


this_class = ThisClass()
celery_app = Celery("tasks", broker="amqp://guest@localhost//")


@worker_init.connect
def WorkerReady(**kwargs):
  this_class.Start()


@worker_process_shutdown.connect
def StopPollingSensors(**kwargs):
  this_class.Stop()
```

This Celery script is supposed to create an instance of ThisClass as this_class, and run this_class.Start() when Celery starts.  When Celery is shutting down, it is supposed to call this_class.Stop(), which gracefully exits the Thread in ThisClass and Celery cleanly exits.

However, when I hit Ctrl-C in Celery to signal a SIGINT, this_class's thread continues to run and Celery does not exit, even after multiple SIGTERMs are issued.  What confuses me is if I slip a print statement in ThisClass.Stop, I see it.  Furthermore, if I add `sleep(5); this_class.Stop()` after `this_class.Start()`, the thread starts and stops as expected, and Celery will exit normally when issued a SIGINT.

How am I supposed to terminate threading.Thread instances in a Celery-based script?

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating the `Event` object externally, and passing it to a `Thread` subclass.  The thread loops on the event object.  When an external function calls `Event.set()`, the thread loop exits out of the `while` loop cleanly.

```
import sys, time
from threading import Event, Thread, Timer


class ThisClass2(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        super(ThisClass2,self).__init__()
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        print 'thread start'
        while not self.event.wait(timeout=1.0):
            print("thread: Hello, world!")
        print 'thread done'


event2 = Event()
x = ThisClass2(event2)
x.start()

print 'okay'
time.sleep(1)

print 'signaling event'
event2.set()

print 'waiting'
x.join()
```

Example output:

```
thread start
okay
thread: Hello, world!
signaling event
waiting
thread done
```

Comment: I have adapted your script to use Celery: http://pastie.org/9236180  Both of our threading.Event methods to end the loop works outside of Celery, but not when using Celery.  Even in the paste above, .set() really does set the Event, but the main loop's Event isn't set, apparently.  Maybe it has something to do with scopes in Celery?  Perhaps Celery is copying objects instead of mutating them directly?